# Software exposed Bit width in C

Tags: c, bit, cpu-registers

I have two questions:

1. Is there any method to specify or limit the bit widths used for integer variables in a C program?
2. Is there any way to monitor the actual bit usage for a variable in a C program? What I mean by bit usage is, in some programs when a register is allocated for a variable not all the bits of that register are used for calculations. Hence when a program is executed can we monitor how many bits in a register have been actually changed through out the execution of a program?

Comment: For 1, yes. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdint.h#stdint.h).

Comment: all of the bits are used in the calculation, what do you mean?  you cannot undo the wiring of the processor on the fly...

Comment: 1) yes, use AND.  2) you cannot monitor registers from C...

Comment: @dwelch He's talking about the ability of some x86 instructions to only affect part of a register. AL, AH, AX, EAX all use the same register, but the first three only use part of it. That can be used to advantage in assembly language programs, but not in a C program.

Comment: @user3386109 Yes you're right I am trying to build a compiler which make use of that feature and translates C programs to assembly instructions in a optimum manner, Is there any processor or hardware platform which turn down slices of bus when they are not used?

Comment: If the CPU is CMOS (like all modern CPUs) then each transistor only consumes power (draws current) when changing state. Therefore it doesn't make sense to "turn off" slices of the bus or register because that's already what's happening - the unchanged bits (regardless weather it's 1 or 0) don't consume power. What modern CPU architectures do instead to conserve power is to turn the clock line off (that's the part that changes most often after all) to unused hardware. For example, if it detects that in the next 100 or so instructions you're not using the FPU it stops clocking the FPU.

Comment: "Is there any processor or hardware platform which turn down slices of bus?"  Not that I'm aware of. On the contrary, most processors cache both data and code. A cache miss will cause the processor to read many bytes into the cache using the full bus width, regardless of how little data is needed to satisfy the current request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use fixed width (or guaranteed-at-least-this-many-bits) types in C as of the 1999 standard, see e.g. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types) or any decent C description, defined in the `inttypes.h` C header (called `cinttypes` in C++), also in `stdint.h` (C) or `cstdint` (C++).

You certainly can check for each computation what the values of the values could be, and limit the variables acordingly. But unless you are *seriously* strapped for space, I'd just forget about this. In many cases using "just large enough" data types wastes space (and computation time) by having to cast small values to the natural widths for computation, and then cast back. Beware of [premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization), and even more of optimizing the wrong code (*measure* if the performance is enough, and if not, where modifications are worthwhile, before digging in to make code "better").

Answer (score 0):

You have limited control if you use `<stdint.h>`.

On most systems, it will provide:

- `int8_t` and `uint8_t` for 8-bit integers.
- `int16_t` and `uint16_t` for 16-bit integers.
- `int32_t` and `uint32_t` for 32-bit integers.
- `int64_t` and `uint64_t` for 64-bit integers.

You don't usually get other choices.  However, you might be able to use a bit-field to get a more arbitrary size value:

```
typedef struct int24_t
{
    signed int b24:24;
} int24_t;
```

This might occupy more than 24 bits (probably 32 bits), but arithmetic will end up being 24-bit.  You're not constrained to a power of 2, or even a multiple of 2:

```
typedef struct int13_t
{
    signed int b13:13;
} int13_t;
```